# KeyboardEvent event.key and event.code are different

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keydown, keyup

Why are `event.key and` `event.code` sometimes different?

It appears when I change the layout from `QWERTY` to `QWERTZ` even if I use a `QWERTZ` keyboard...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue in the past, while working in a project.

Key references the key value representation.

keyCode references the ASCII value from that key.

Check this for a better explanation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup

Comment: Sorry I meant event.key and event.code! Not keyCode

Comment: Np, in that MDN reference you can find  a reference, of what event.code and event.key are.